# Submission error is not shown on react final form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-final-form, react-forms

I'm having troubles with React-Final-Form library. From the `onSubmit` function, I return a validation error, but it is not displayed on the form itself. Here you can see my code:

My form:

```
<Form
                                       onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                                        initialValues={{}}
                                        validate={
                                            values => {
                                                const errors = {}
                                                if (!values.username) {
                                                    errors.username = "This field is required"
                                                }
                                                if (!values.password) {
                                                    errors.password = "This field is required"
                                                }
                                                return errors
                                            }
                                        }
                                        render={({submitError, handleSubmit, submitting, values}) => (
                                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                                    <Field name="username">
                                                        {({input, meta}) => (
                                                            <>
                                                                <input {...input} type="text" placeholder="Username"
                                                                       className={"form-control" + ((meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched ? " is-invalid" : "")}/>
                                                                {(meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched ?
                                                                    <div
                                                                        className="invalid-feedback">{meta.error || meta.submitError}</div> : null
                                                                }
                                                            </>
                                                        )}
                                                    </Field>
                                                    {submitError && (
                                                        <div>{submitError}</div>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <label>Password</label>
                                                    <Field name="password">
                                                        {({input, meta}) => (
                                                            <>
                                                                <input {...input} type="password"
                                                                       placeholder="Password"
                                                                       className={"form-control" + ((meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched ? " is-invalid" : "")}/>
                                                                {(meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched ?
                                                                    <div
                                                                        className="invalid-feedback">{meta.error || meta.submitError}</div> : null
                                                                }
                                                            </>
                                                        )}
                                                    </Field>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}
                                                        className="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary">Log In
                                                </button>
                                                <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
                                            </form>
                                        )}
                                    />
```

My onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit = async values => {
        const errors = {}
        let loginData = {
            username: values.username,
            password: values.password
        }
        usersAPI.getCSRF().then((response) => {
            usersAPI.login(loginData)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.login_status === "Incorrect data") {
                        console.log("Invalid data")
                        errors.username = "Invalid login or password"
                        errors.password = "Invalid login or password"
                        return errors
                    } else {
                        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
                        this.props.setAuthState(true)
                        console.log("Logged in successfully")
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
    }
```

The problem is in axios request. If my back-end server sends the response that credentials are invalid, then `console.log("Invalid data")` will appear in console but nothing will happen with form. If I comment my axios request and just leave this code:

```
onSubmit = async values => {
        return {username: "Invalid data"}
    }
```

So, in this case everything works correct. Who can tell me How can I optimize my axios request so after that my form will get submission errors that returned from

```
errors.username = "Invalid login or password"
errors.password = "Invalid login or password"
return errors
```

Comment: Just FYI - since you're not awaiting calls, you don't need to use the `async` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I found mistake. Mistake was in my return function. It just returns this value to  `usersAPI.getCSRF()` function, not to global `onSubmit` function. I made some changes so my final code looks like this:

```
onSubmit = values => {
        let loginData = {
            username: values.username,
            password: values.password
        }
        let success = false;
        usersAPI.getCSRF().then((response) => {
            usersAPI.login(loginData)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.data.login_status !== "Incorrect data") {
                        success = true
                        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        })
        if (success) this.props.setAuthState(true)
        else return {username: "Incorrect username or password", password: "Incorrect username or password"}
    }
```

Comment: instead you could add a return right before usersAPI.getCSRF() and that should work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days on the same issue (submission errors not displaying) and wanted to post my solution here in case anyone else ran into my issue because I could not find it online.

Basically I have a form set up like so:

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
    ...
    return {username: 'required'} // errors object
}

<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
>
{({values}) => (
  <form>
    <a onClick={() => onSubmit(values)}>save</a>
    ...restOfForm
  </form>
)}
</Form>
```

The issue above is that I am calling my "onSubmit" function directly, so the returned submission errors go nowhere. I needed to call the "handleSubmit" function passed into the render function to populate the errors like so:

```js
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
    {({values, handleSubmit}) => (
      <form>
        <a onClick={() => handleSubmit(values)}>save</a>
        ...restOfForm
      </form>
    )}
    </Form>
```